# Rails nginx passenger and rake commands

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nginx

I'm running my rails application with the help of passenger. And i see in `top` that it run's as www-data user, but when i try to run under this user this command:

`rake ts:index`

i get like access denied

when i'm under root (run under root `rake ts:index`) - all is ok...

what is better:

to make passenger running as root (how to do that)

or

what ever could i do?

**how to do, that sphinx could reindex database?**

part of code in method:

```
def self.reindexDB
      `rake ts:index`
    end
```

Comment: `but when i try to run under this user` by this user you mean `www-data` user ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if what you're doing is good or not, because if you run that rake command in `root` user, I believe the output files (index files) will be owned by the `root` user, with wrong permissions those files won't be accessible by your own server (`www-data`),

I think the best way to handle this is to add your own user ( the one you use to ssh on the server ) to the `www-data` group
There's 2 ways to do that

1. Command line: like `sudo usermod -a -G www-data [your-user]`
2. Editing `/etc/group`:
   Edit the `/etc/group` file and look for the line that starts with `www-data` then append your own user in it, it should look something like this at the end

   ```
   www-data:x:33:[your-user]
   ```

   save the file then you need to logout and log back in to find the changes,

I believe after this you'll be able to run the command by your own user and it will still have access to the `www-data` owned files.